How to get and install eng flavor of Android in android emulator?
I have an app that refuses to run unless it is running in an eng build.
MTKThermalManager.apk I would like to have a look at what this app is, since there is very little information about it online and antivirus marks it as dangerous.
When you run this app from quick shortcut maker, it gives you a bubble with:
"Only supported in eng build."
Which I guess means I need an eng build of android.
I am not asking what this app is, or what you think it does.
Unless you know exactly what it does. It is clear that it is supposed to be doing something with thermal management.
I want to run it and see it.
Is there a way how to get an eng build of Android that I can run in Android Studio emulator?
The eng build has some different default features:
Difference between eng and user-debug build in Android
Thanks.

If it is for thermal management, it may only work correctly on specific hardware. You may want to try Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project, although Reverse Engineering StackExchange has overlap.

Reverse engineering was not a bad idea. I got it running.
